# Boolean indexing on Nan values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame as follows-

```
                 ID        Date Element  Data_Value    day  max   min
131541  USC00203712  2015-02-16    TMIN       -29.4  02-16  NaN -29.4
131566  USC00203712  2015-02-16    TMAX       -12.2  02-16  NaN   NaN
131638  USC00208972  2015-02-16    TMAX       -15.6  02-16  NaN   NaN
131641  USC00208972  2015-02-16    TMIN       -29.4  02-16  NaN -29.4
131727  USC00201250  2015-02-16    TMAX       -13.9  02-16  NaN   NaN
131728  USC00201250  2015-02-16    TMIN       -28.9  02-16  NaN -28.9
```

I want to drop rows where both 'max' and 'min' are Nan, such as the row with index 131566, 131638 etc. here.

I was able to create the correct boolean mask with -

```
bool = ~((~df['min'].notnull()) & (~df['max'].notnull()))
```

On applying this mask to the Frame I get

```
                 ID        Date Element  Data_Value    day  max   min
131541  USC00203712  2015-02-16    TMIN       -29.4  02-16  NaN -29.4
131566          NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
131638          NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
131641  USC00208972  2015-02-16    TMIN       -29.4  02-16  NaN -29.4
131727          NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
131728  USC00201250  2015-02-16    TMIN       -28.9  02-16  NaN -28.9
```

Now I can't simply use the dropna() method because that would drop all of the rows and columns. Any way to circumvent this?

Comment: What is `min` and what is `max` here?

Comment: They are the column names. I have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`df.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) to check for null values and [`df.all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) along `axis=1` to check if all values in the list of columns are `NaN`:

```
l=['max','min'] #list of cols to check
df[~df[l].isna().all(1)]
```

---

```
                 ID        Date Element  Data_Value    day  max   min
131541  USC00203712  2015-02-16    TMIN       -29.4  02-16  NaN -29.4
131641  USC00208972  2015-02-16    TMIN       -29.4  02-16  NaN -29.4
131728  USC00201250  2015-02-16    TMIN       -28.9  02-16  NaN -28.9
```

Answer (score 2):

## First Solution

simply apply notnull with or

```
df[(df['min'].notnull())| (df['max'].notnull())]
```

## Second Sol

Use `.isnull()` on both columns and place 1 on any temp column in my case `bool_check`

then filter `bool_check!=1`

and drop `bool_check`

```
df.loc[(df['max'].isnull()) &(df['min'].isnull()),"bool_check"]=1
res = df[df['bool_check']!=1]
res.drop(['bool_check],axis=1,inplace=True)
```